# Analyzing 3D data: What can be done?

Tags: correlation, experiment-design, compression

I am new to this kind of analysis, and I want to know what values I can look at in 3D data.
The data itself is a 3D volume $(x,y,z)$ with a floating point value in every coordinate.
It is a *hyperspectral image*, meaning: the $z$-space is the same $xy$ plane at a different wavelength. 
[Here is an example from the internet of a hyperspectral image](http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v3/n11/images/nphoton.2009.205-f3.jpg).

The goal is to find **characteristics** in the data that can be exploited to compress it.

How could I approach this? [See also [PCA of hyperspectral image data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/88861/32036) ]