# PCA of hyperspectral image data

Tags: r, pca, matlab

I have some hyperspectral image data similar to [this](http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v3/n11/images/nphoton.2009.205-f3.jpg), and I want to do a PCA on it. 
The problem: I've never done a PCA, and its specially difficult for me to do it on 3D data.

How can I do it in MATLAB or R? [See also [Analyzing 3D data: What can be done?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/88859/32036) ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to do it is to transform your 3D data into a vector. This is a bit rough but often works fine in practice.
Then you can use the `prcomp`function from the R `base` package to compute PCA.

You can also use the "Multilinear Principal Component Analysis of Tensor Objects" (MPCA) proposed by [Lu et al. (2008)](http://www.dsp.toronto.edu/~haiping/Publication/MPCA_TNN08_rev2010.pdf). It answers your question directly, as it does PCA on multidimensional objects. An implementation of their algorithm is available in MATLAB [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26168-multilinear-principal-component-analysis-mpca).

Answer (score 3):

Put the hyperspectral (HS) image into a DxN matrix X where D is the dimension of  the data (no of HS bands) and N is the number of HS pixels; then calculate the  covariance of X:

```
   CovMat = cov(X');  %'
```

Now suppose you are interested in only 3 principal components so you need to 
find the 3 directions that the variance of the data is largest:

```
   [V E] = eigs(CovMat, 3);
```

The first 3 cols of V are the first 3 principal components
and forms the subspace that you are projecting the data to:

```
   A = [V(:,1) V(:,2) V(:,3)];
```

Project your data to that subspace:

```
   Y = X'*A;  %'
```

This is the visualization of X projected to its 1st 3 principal components:

```
   figure; plot3(Y(:, 1), Y(:, 2), Y(:, 3), '.')
```

If image is very large randomly choose a subset of the pixels to make X smaller.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have a look at the "*hyperspec*" package in R. http://hyperspec.r-forge.r-project.org/ has a very clear documentation for dealing with hyperspectral data. I would suggest to use MATLAB if you would like to proceed further than PCA.